# Optimizepress and Sharrre social buttons

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter

Can anyone help with changing default twitter text in Sharrre social feature in OptimizePress 2 (wordpress).

I tracked code to global.min.js (minified version of global.js) where in init_sharrre() happens inserting of iframe. I have no idea how to change default tweet text (menu in OP doesn't allow this, only user etc.). The text itself is in the iframe src as a link param. Can anyone help with this? I would appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after few hours of looking... It's located in the jquery.sharrre.js file. Can be overwritten by adding localOptions.text = "Custom text here"; to global.js (and minifying it).